# Selenium Hub failures with chromedriver on Linux

Tags: java, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, ui-testing

I'm trying to run Selenium Hub and one node (currently on the same ubuntu 64 bit VM) on oracle jvm 1.8.71 64 bit.

My installation and running params are as follows:

Running the hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.50.0.jar -debug -role hub
```

Running the node:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.50.0.jar -debug -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5555 -browser browserName=chrome, maxInstances=1, platform=Linux -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/tmp/selenium/chromedriver
```

Chromedriver is of the latest version (2.20.353124 as appears in log).

Now My Java test is rather simple. I run it on Windows from my IDE:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    long sleepBetweenTests = ...; // I give 0 here
    int testNumber = ... ; // for example 1000

    for(int i = 0; i < testNumber; i++) {
        System.out.print("[ " + new Date() + "] running test #: " + i);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        runSingleTest();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("  Took : " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepBetweenTests);
        }catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

    }
}



private void runSingleTest() throws MalformedURLException {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("--window-size=1920,1080"));
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("<HOST_COMES_HERE>:4444/wd/hub"),capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        try {
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            // Find the text input element by its name
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

            // Enter something to search for
            element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

            // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
            element.submit();

        }catch(Throwable t) {
            // I just want to see it:
            System.err.println(t);
        }
        finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

Now what I see is that **__sometimes__** (sporadically) chrome fails to load and gets stuck. Most of the cases it works fine, I see chrome opens and the test runs as expected. Once this happens - any subsequent attempts to rerun the test will fail right from the very beginning.
I don't see any error in logs of neither node nor hub, I don't see any exception on test (besides the fact that it gets stuck).

So, two questions:

- How to enable logs of chromedriver itself?
- In general :) Does anyone can shed some light on this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance, any help is highly appreciated :)